# bash loop with the variable name inside file name

Tags: bash

I am trying to run a loop where the variable condition is inside the file name, and not at the end. I'm wondering what the syntax is? Here is the code I tried to run:

```
for (( c = 479; c <= 480; c++ ))
do
fastqc --thread 32 SRR9049$c$_pass.fastq
done
```

Where two example names would be `SRR9049479_pass.fastq` and `SRR9049480_pass.fastq`

This gives the output

```
Skipping 'SRR9049479.fastq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
Skipping 'SRR9049480.fastq' which didn't exist, or couldn't be read
```

How do I change `SRR9049$c$_pass.fastq` so that it can read the ending of the file? Thank you!

Comment: `SRR9049${c}_pass.fastq`

Comment: Your code tries to use a variable named `$_pass`, which doesn't exist.